# Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, exception

When I run the below code, I get an exception and I don't know why.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
at simulateur.Simulateur.main(Simulateur.java:218)
```

Line 218 is for : *for(Request r : Sys.queue)* and Sys.queue is an ArrayList

```
    //*************** DispatchRequest ***************
    if(!Sys.queue.isEmpty())
    {
        algo = new SortingAlgo(Sys.queue, clock);
        Sys.queue = algo.sorted_queue;
        for(Request r : Sys.queue)
        {
            {       
                for(Porter p : p_i.porList)
                {

                    if(p.p_state.equals("Available"))
                    {
                        ...
                        ...
                        Sys.queue.remove(r);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're removing from the list while iterating over it, that's a terrible idea and is what's causing this exception to be thrown. Research how to properly remove an element from an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Have you read the document about this exception? ArrayList?

Comment: What does a ConcurrentModificationException mean? (You tell me, since you read the documentation that tells you what it means, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
for(Request r : Sys.queue)
{
    {       
        for(Porter p : p_i.porList)
        {

            if(p.p_state.equals("Available"))
            {
                ...
                ...
                Sys.queue.remove(r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `for` loop is iterating over the elements of `Sys.queue` while at the same time modifying the contents of the variable by invoking `Sys.queue.remove(r);`

You can fix this by keeping track of elements you want to remove in a separate list/queue and then using the [`removeAll(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) method of `ArrayList`

For example:

```
for(Request r : Sys.queue)
{
    {       
        for(Porter p : p_i.porList)
        {

            if(p.p_state.equals("Available"))
            {
                ...
                ...
                itemsToRemove.add(r);
            }
        }
    }
}
Sys.queue.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to remove from an `ArrayList` while you're iterating over it. However you can remove directly from the iterator itself using the `Iterator.remove()` method.

The enhanced for loop that you're using to iterate over `Sys.queue` doesn't expose the iterator, but if you change it to an old-style for-loop, you can access the remove method:

```
if(!Sys.queue.isEmpty())
{
    algo = new SortingAlgo(Sys.queue, clock);
    Sys.queue = algo.sorted_queue;
    // For-loop on next line changed to old-style for-loop:
    for (Iterator<Request> iterator = Sys.queue.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        Request r = iterator.next();
        {       
            for(Porter p : p_i.porList)
            {
                if(p.p_state.equals("Available"))
                {
                    iterator.remove(); // The safe way to remove while iterating
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) for a good explanation on why this exception happens. In you case, you're iterating over a array while trying to change it. As said in javadoc.

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

You either want to collect all the elements you want to remove into a list and then do a removeAll() at the very end or put all the elements you don't want to remove into another list & clear this list.